# How to Save the Captured Image from Webcam into Project Folder/Specific Folder

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

I'm trying to save the picturebox image that has been captured using the Webcam.
I'm using AForget.NET.

What i want to do is I want that picturebox image to be saved into Project/Specific Folder when i click Ok button and get that path that has been save to folder.

I'm getting error of GDI +

Here's my Code

```
RegisterCustomer _regCustomer;

    public UpdateImageCapture(RegisterCustomer regCustomer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _regCustomer = regCustomer;
    }

    ImageHelper img = new ImageHelper();

    private void ImageCapture_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        img.ImageSettings
        (
            img._captureDevice,
            img.finalFrame,
            cboxWebcamType
        );

        img.finalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);

        btnOk.Hide();
        btnCancel.Hide();
    }

private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
        picPreviewImage.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
}
```

These code specify that when the button capture is clicked the picCaptureImage(Picturebox2) will get the clone copy of picPreviewImage(Picturebox1)

NOTE: Picturebox1 show yourself from a webcam

```
private void BtnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        picCapturedImage.Image = (Bitmap)picPreviewImage.Image.Clone();
        picCapturedImage.BringToFront();
        btnCapture.Hide();
        btnOk.Show();
        btnCancel.Show();
}

private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image);
            var newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\dieth\source\repos\SalesInventorySystem\SalesInventorySystem\Resources", ImageFormat.Png);
            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL");
        }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to output an Image as a Directory instead of a File. + Don't hard-code paths and don't reference paths in the Application Project: when you deploy your application, that path won't exist and you'll have another problem. Give your Users means to configure an output directory path using a standard dialog. Try/Catch `IOExceptions`.

Comment: What do you mean by standard dialog ? can you elaborate it ?

Comment: [FolderBrowserDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , but when i tried to capture an image again , it just replacing the image from that file.

```
if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
            picCapturedImage.Image.Save(@"..\..\Resources\ImageCapture.Png", ImageFormat.Png);
```